# Voltage Question

Tags: voltmeter

How is voltage measured in a voltmeter, is it the difference between the voltages that are measured. If you can, please explain how to do part ***B*** of the question.(I am trying to solve this question and it would be easier if I knew this)[image: the question I am referring to] Thanks. =)

Comment: your course instructor should be made aware that some of the students do not know how a voltmeter operates .... that should have been one of the first things that was taught

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as the name suggests, a volt-meter will measure the *difference* in voltage between its two terminals.

You can assume that the voltmeter has infinite resistance and doesn't load the circuit in any way.

As this is a homework question we need you to show your work and where you are stuck.

Comment: The (or maybe a) meta-answer is that **all** voltages are differences.  There is no absolute "zero volts" -- only differences in voltage between point A and point B.  So there's nothing that a voltmeter *can* do other than measure the difference between two points.  (Well, it could burn up when you turn it on -- there's nothing that a *correctly operating* voltmeter can do, etc.)

Comment: In addition to @TimWescott's comment, replacing "difference in voltage" with "difference in potential" would be more correct, and I think it's important to stress the subtle difference between the two.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comment. It helped me understand more clearly. =) =) =) =) =) =) =) =) =) =)

Answer (score 1):

If I answer your homework question will I get in trouble? The 500 and the 1K are in series and form a voltage divider. Calculate the voltage at the center with respect to (for example) the right side power line.
The 1K and the 3K also form a voltage divider. Calculate that center voltage with respect to the same power line. The voltmeter as shown will read the difference between the 2 center point voltages.
The answer is .:.:.:.:. !   (dragon boat)